# How to Track Errors in SCSS partial files on webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-4

I'm using **SCSS** with **webpack** and I wondering if there a way of

How to Track **Errors** in SCSS **partial files** ?

rather than emitting errors on the **main SCSS file** [which I importing all partials files]

for example :

```js
    ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/f--6-2!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-4!./src/sass/main.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/images/bg-f.png' in 'C:\ProdSpace\dental\src\sass'
     @ ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/resolv!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-4!./src/sass/main.scss) 14:39-74
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

in this case I try to remmeber and search where I used this file

`./assets/images/bg-f.png`

to reach to source error ... Is there a better way plz

Thanks ...